# backdrop-filter not working with <table> tag

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors, frontend

I want to give Glassmorphism effect to each row in table tag and backdrop-filter is not working with tr tag. How to give blur effect to row or any alternative css property for achieve it ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<Style>
  body {
    background: rgb(179, 179, 201);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179, 179, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(216, 216, 224, 1) 99%);
  }
  
  table {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 40px;
  }
  
  tr {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    background: rgba( 4, 9, 210, 0.30);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
    backdrop-filter: blur( 2.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 2.5px);
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <table cellspacing=0>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `filter: blur( 2.5px );`.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov It will give blur effect to text

Comment: Your style isn't closed

Comment: @Coll Still not working

Comment: Which browser are you using? If it's Firefox `backdrop-filter()`s are not on by default.

Comment: Beware, backdrop-filter isn't supported by Firefox. Also, applying backdrop-filter to the TD instead of row produces intended results though invisible without a definitive image behind

Comment: Yeah, alternative solutions if Firefox support is an issue can be uses SVG's as backgrounds.

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964468/webkit-backdrop-filter-with-javascript-cross-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the backdrop-filter to the `td` instead produces the intended effect. I've also dropped in a more defined image to show results.

```
body{
    background: rgb(179,179,201);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179,179,201,1) 0%, rgba(216,216,224,1) 99%);
    background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000);
}
table{
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width:50%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 40px;
}
tr{
    height: 100px;
    padding:50px;
    background: rgba( 4, 9, 210, 0.30 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 );
}
td {
    backdrop-filter: blur( 10px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10px );
}
```

Be sure to close your style element. Beware, backdrop-filter doesn't work on Firefox by default.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to solve the transition points between `td` elements. But +1 from me this seems to be the best alternative to SVG solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Limited Support (tested on Safari, no Chrome/default Firefox support)*

Make sure the opening `<style>` tag starts with a lower case. Also for the blur effects to be prominent you might need a background image or some elements behind the `tr` elements. Below I put a `div` (`#Test_Rectangle`) to show the effects of the `backdrop-filter()`. Keep in mind to beware of the lack of support for backdrop-filters in Firefox's default configuration. Press the blue <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see the results:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(179, 179, 201);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179, 179, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(216, 216, 224, 1) 99%);
}

#Test_Rectangle{
position: absolute;
height: 50vw;
width: 50vw;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: cyan;
}

table {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 40px;
}

tr {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(4, 9, 210, 0.30);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="Test_Rectangle"></div>

  <table cellspacing=0>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working on Chrome88, though I'm not sure why. Working as intended on Safari14.

Comment: @Coll Nice catch, support for this is sure a mess. If anything I guess the safest way is an SVG.